# Redis timeseries - sum all hits

Tags: python, redis, redistimeseries

I use this python client:
https://github.com/ryananguiano/python-redis-timeseries

How can I sum all hits?

```
ts = TimeSeries(client)
```

If I understand, when I query `get_total_hits()`, I have to pick one of:

```
ts.granularities
OrderedDict([('1minute', {'duration': 60, 'ttl': 3600}), ('5minute', {'duration': 300, 'ttl': 21600}), ('10minute', {'duration': 600, 'ttl': 43200}), ('1hour', {'duration': 3600, 'ttl': 604800}), ('1day', {'duration': 86400, 'ttl': 2678400})])
```

e.g

```
ts.get_total_hits('metric', '1minute', 2)
```

Can I write something like 'all' instead of '1minute'?
I want to sum all the hits.

I could set '1day' and a very large number, but I hope there's a better way.

Second, what is the performance of such query?

Comment: Are you using RedisTimeSeries? which client are you using?

Comment: @GuyKorland python client

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your options for [this client](https://github.com/ryananguiano/python-redis-timeseries/blob/997ff4dec38489362aca0288ab35b29a49c3bf41/redis_timeseries.py#L29) are:

1minute, 5minute, 10minute, 1hour, 1day